# memory error while reading csv file from s3 using pandas & boto3. Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read a 1.5 GB file from s3 using pandas & boto3
Today I had to pivot a 36 GB deep file into a wide file (1.5 GB) .
I wrote the 1.5 GB file to local and checked if everything was alright using pandas.read_csv(). It read without any issues.

But after copying to s3 while reading using boto3 the code errors out due to a strange memory error. The code usually works fine for file sizes of 300 to 1 GB.

I am currently unable to pin-point where exactly the error is coming from. I tried copying the file again to s3 & still getting the same memory error while reading.

code to read from s3:

```
input_file_obj= s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
input_file_content= input_file_obj["Body"].read()
df=pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(input_file_content), index_col=None, delimiter=delim,header=hdr,low_memory=False)
```

I am thinking the ram couldn't be the issue since it has 32 GBs of RAM available in the EC2 machine that I am using. Also the machine that I am working on is Unix.

Sample error :

```
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd70340c3e4 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c503)[0x7fd71d737503]
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(parser_cleanup+0x1a)[0x7fd70340467a]
```

[link](https://pastebin.com/77SdcFGz) to complete error log

Comment: Do you get the same error if in `read_csv` you set `engine='python'` or `low_memory=True`?  A little [googling](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9328#issuecomment-296998879) suggests this may have to do with C incompatibilities, your EC2 image may need some kind of updating if you want it to work as-is.

Comment: @andrew_reece i tired giving `low_memory=False` and it worked like a charm. I referred Google and pandas documentation but it doesn't shed much light on this parameter. Currently testing all modules which use this function to see if it has any side effect . Could you explain the significance of this parameter in detail if you are aware

Comment: Also the difference between read from local and s3 was the value of this one parameter. That's why I tested it intially after you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this error on EC2/S3 but not locally may be due to the C environment on the VM instance you're using. Your local machine may just have a more compatible C setup than whatever came bundled on your VM.

To fix the issue, consider setting `engine='python'` or `low_memory=True` in `read_csv()`.  Both the `engine` and `low_memory` arguments in `read_csv()` seem to engage the underlying C implementation.  This [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9328#issuecomment-296998879) identified a similar error, and found that to be the problem.

Fair warning: I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to speak confidently on how it works with C under the hood.  According to OP comments these parameter value adjustments seemed to solve the problem, but I'd welcome anyone with more experience to chime in here.

Comment: Sorry when i meant local i meant 'read from a storage path in ec2' machine itself vs read from s3 using ec2 machine. So the `low_memory=False` was causing the issue with s3 since read from local storage it was by default true.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It seems like this has to do with how the Python C parser reads the S3 bucket.  Pandas does this a little differently with S3, compared to how local files are read in, see discussion [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11073).  Since that PR went in, `read_csv()` for S3 opens a pipe to S3 but doesn't download the whole thing at once.  That may be where the underlying C configuration hits a problem, based on how memory is allocated when reading from the stream.  Best guess!

Comment: As per the link u shared, i don't seem to have anything to with stream-csv-from-s3 . Let me try to read from local unix storage with low_memory = False to see if they issue is with s3 alone or pandas itself.